# Analysis of a comparator circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, homework

I am struggling to analyze this (admittedly homework) Op-Amp circuit.

[image: circuit]

---

### Voltage divider approach

Now if we treat the input into the negative terminal as a voltage divider we get

$$
V_- = 10V* \frac{5}{20}
$$

It has been kindly pointed out in the comments (thank you Andy aka), that this is a [comparator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator) circuit.

A comparator circuit is going to output a \$V_{cc+}\$ if \$V_{+} > V_{-}\$ and \$V_{cc-}\$ otherwise.

\$V_o\$ is therefore going to roughly be (ignoring slew rate)
[image: output voltage]

Is this a sensible analysis, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Your schematic does not show an Rf

Comment: Furthermore, there is no feedback. Any formula you have for an op amp circuit with negative feedback will not apply here.

Comment: It's not an op-amp; it's a comparator. When you drew the circuit using the tool, you made a mistake in assuming an op-amp and that has compounded your thinking difficulty. Show a picture of the actual homework question.

Comment: I think you should go talk to your instructor. I think you have some very fundamental confusion about op amp circuits, which is too broad to address here.

Comment: @Andyaka I have updated the question with the circuit from the exercise

Comment: It doesn't say it's an op-amp does it. So, all your thoughts about it being similar to a differential op-amp are misconceptions. So, fix your question to remove those misconceptions and google what a comparator does.

Comment: @Andyaka It says "In the following circuit an ideal operational amplifier is used"

Comment: Then you are still not providing the correct source information I asked for. You can use an op-amp as a comparator but, you have to treat the circuit as a comparator.

Comment: Why R3=0? Do you want to remove R3? In this case set R3 to infinite. Your formula for Vo is OK.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you for pointing out this is a comparator circuit! I would have completely missed it. I have updated the question with a comparator circuit analysis, if you are interested in checking it out :D (I would also totally understand if not, you already helped me plenty. Thank you!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is this a sensible analysis, or am I missing something here?*

You are no longer missing anything and your waveform looks nearly correct (more below).

- Always look for negative feedback when assuming an op-amp circuit.
- For comparator circuits either no feedback is used or a little bit of positive feedback.
- The positive feedback is useful to avoid the output toggling rapidly as both inputs get close. It would slightly skew your waveforms and is a little bit more complex to analyse but, nevertheless, it might be important in more complex homework problems.

<strike>However, you should really analyse the input waveform a little more carefully should you want a better answer. I estimate that the input waveform rises to 9 volts in about 1 second and, that means it crosses the 5 volt level at about five-ninths of a second (555.6 ms). If you look at your waveform, the output toggles negative to positive at a little less than 0.3 seconds so, strictly speaking your answer isn't as accurate as it should be.</strike>

So, after much thought, the ramping input crosses the 2.5 volts (the threshold) at 277.7 ms and your graph looks good.

Comment: hmm, why are we looking at 5V? Is my V- computation incorrect? (10*5/20=2.5V). I used the 2.5V as the reference voltage

Comment: @sjaustirni you are absolutely correct and I shall amend my answer accordingly. I don't know where I'd got 5 volts from!!!